# Integrating js randomizer that displays results that can be styled with css.

Tags: java, javascript, css

I have only done mostly front end stuff in the past. HTML/CSS and I am trying to make something that requires some scripting but I am not sure where to even begin looking.

Basically what I am trying to do is the following.

I want to have 3 dice that can randomly show a face when the page is refreshed or a button is hit the faces are 1-6, each die has a different color, each face and each color have a set of descriptions they are linked to.

So lets say I refresh the page, I want each die to show a different face.

Then underneath there is multiple sections for each die so:

Red Die 6: (Random description from listA of 6)

Green Die 2: (Random description from listB of 6)

Black Die 4: (Random description from listC of 6)

Can those descriptions be pulled from an XML file that is going to be changed frequently?

Can they be displayed inside their own collapsable/expandable DIV in order to style the text?

I don't know if this might be too complicated and way over my head.

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't be very complicated.  Here's a really basic JSFiddle to play around with:  http://jsfiddle.net/gUq7B/

For the HTML we have 3 paragraph tags that we'll use to show the dice.  These could be div's or images or anything else you'll end up using on your site.

```
<p id="dice1"></p>
<p id="dice2"></p>
<p id="dice3"></p>
```

Next we'll want to declare our random variables using Javascript  (I have 3 separate variables for simplicity but in production you may want to create a function to product the random number):

```
var dice1rand = Math.floor((Math.random()*6)+1);
var dice2rand = Math.floor((Math.random()*6)+1);
var dice3rand = Math.floor((Math.random()*6)+1);
```

Then we can set the paragraphs to display the values:

```
document.getElementById("dice1").innerHTML = dice1rand;
document.getElementById("dice2").innerHTML = dice2rand;
document.getElementById("dice3").innerHTML = dice3rand;
```

And finally we can add some logic rules to set the CSS for the paragraph elements.  Here's a sample for setting the background color using JQuery:

```
if (dice1rand === 1) $("#dice1").addClass("red");
if (dice2rand === 2) $("#dice2").addClass("green");
```

Once you get that working, you can switch out the CSS logic with a function to grab the data out of your XML file.